# Firebase 5.0 RTD querying data

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am simply trying to get all the data from my RTD into an array to iterate over. The following code returns an undefined, what am I missing?

```
export class AppComponent {
  cuisines$: Observable<any[]>;
  cuisines: any[];

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.cuisines$ = db.list('/cuisines').valueChanges();
    this.cuisines$.subscribe(x => this.cuisines = x);
    console.log(this.cuisines);
  }
}
```

UPDATE: I switched over to the Cloud Firestore and the following code returns my array. Maybe Cloud Firestore is the way to go!

```
export class AppComponent {
  items: any[];
  items$: Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
    this.items$ = db.collection('items').valueChanges();
    this.items$.subscribe(x => {
      this.items = x;
      console.log(this.items);
    });
  }
}
```

[image: Firebase Cloudstore]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing order of execution.
Your console.log is executed right after previous assignment. And it will take some time before subscription will deliver any results.

Move your console.log inside the subscribe:

```
this.cuisines$.subscribe(x =>{
this.cuisines = x;
console.log(this.cuisines); // recieved snapshot
this.cuisines.forEach(i=>console.log(i)); //items themselves
});
```

Comment: I had tried it like that too, but I don't get a list of items per se https://imgur.com/a/9MUPs

Comment: you got to iterate over them

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.cuisines$ = db.list('/cuisines').snapshotChanges();
    this.cuisines$.subscribe(x => {
        this.cuisines = x;
        console.log(this.cuisines);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Code should be accompanied with a written explanation on how it fixes the issue in the OP.